# Eventbrite API - Get Events with Classic ASP

Tags: api, asp-classic, eventbrite

I'm restricted to classic ASP and trying to use the following code to get a list of events from a user on Eventbrite:

```
Dim req
Set req = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

response.ContentType="text/xml"
req.open "GET", "https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/user_list_events?app_key=XXXX&user_key=XXXX&user=XXXX", False
req.send
Response.Write(req.responseText)
```

This has worked with other APIs but can't get it to work with Eventbrite. When I test the URL, it works in RESTClient and in my browser. Am I missing something?

Any help is greatly apprciated!

Thanks!
John

Comment: What status property do you get back ? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms767681(v=vs.85).aspx) Pending on the outcome you might want to use a specific version (Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 ) and use the setOption flag to ignore server certificate errors...

Comment: Hi AardVark71, I'm getting a 500 status back. I tried your suggestions but get the same error.

Comment: A status 500 error sounds like a problem with the data your passing.. is that only the app_key and user_key? If there are special characters, you might wanna try using Server.URLencode to be sure

Comment: I tried that as well, Server.URLencode, but it returns the same error:/ Thanks for the suggestions and help though! I tried looking in the logs but couldn't find anything related to that file.

Comment: Please try this call without the additional (optional) 'user' parameter.  
By default, events that are owned by the user account associated with the supplied 'user_key' will be returned.  

The 'user' parameter is only useful for accessing public events from a different user account (the user_key must be omitted in that use-case).

Comment: Hi @ʀɣαɳĵ I removed the 'user' parameter and it returns the same error (w/ and w/o the URLecode). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: perhaps problem with https? are you requesting in a ssl context or from localhost? perhaps you are not allowed to request from a none ssl environment?